# venv vs Anaconda for creating virtual environments

Tags: python, anaconda, python-venv

What's the difference between venv and Anaconda for creating virtual environments?  I grant both create a folder that allows me to pip install packages locally to the project rather than globally to my machine.

My understanding so far is venv is more built-in and lighter weight, and Anaconda is more for those that prefer clicking to typing.  Anaconda also allows me to pip install packages and start up tools where venv is only about creating the local folder, and defaults to pip to do package installs.

What're the benefits and drawbacks of each approach?  In what scenarios would each tool be best?

I grant this is a newbie question, and similar questions have compared pip and venv or discussed pip in Anaconda environments.  I find no question about venv and Anaconda for virtual environments though.

Comment: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/concepts/environments.html?highlight=venv#virtual-environments

Comment: This comment completely got me to the answer. Want to make it into an answer so I can vote it up?

Comment: I would rather not make an answer that is just a link. It's kind of against the rules. Feel free to write your own answer complete with what you learned from that link.

Answer (score 7):

I would like to point out that the link in [sinoroc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11138259/sinoroc)'s comment on the question is a sufficient answer

- see: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/concepts/environments.html?highlight=venv#virtual-environments

However I'll add some details that I feel the Conda docs do not have that will help newer users learn more about the differences between venv and conda environment managment.

Anaconda environments are clunkier but more comprehensive python environments. An anaconda environment contains

- a specific version of python i.e. python 3.6.5
- then the packages that are within that environment (ex: pytorch, beautifulsoup4, pandas...)

venv's virtural environment managment system relies on your computer's (your system's) python. This can be annoying if you are working on two different projects that require two different versions of the same package, say tensorflow 1.1 vs 2.1, then these different versions of tensorflow have differing dependencies. In this situation its much easier to have two anaconda environments for each project.

However, the largest advantage of anaconda is the ability to interface with jupyter notebooks. Personally I have a some standard conda environments depending on what type of project I am working on; the names of these describe their use so I will just list them.

- ml_pytorch_3_6_5 *- an environment for machine learning using pytorch with python 3.6.5*
- ml_pytorch_3_8_10 *- for machine learning using pytorch with python 3.8.10*
- ml_tensorflow_3_6_5 *- for machine learning using tensorflow with python 3.6.5*
- web_dev_apache *- for web develolpment where I use apache servers*
- web_dev_nginx *- for web dev with nginx servers*

This workflow offers advantages over the standard venv management as there are multiple different versions of python on my machine that allow for different purposes. As environments are fairly standard for each purpose I can reuse one from project to project depending on that nature of what I am doing.

Comment: venv takes a -p flag which you can specify a specific version of Python on your system. So the way you worded it is not exactly true. Typically a system python on Linux uses python 2; however, with the -p flag you can specify any version you want.